# Angular: ng-click with a parameter not working

Tags: angularjs

I've got the following HTML:

```
<i style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="addName()" class="icon-plus"></i>
<i style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="delName({{$index}})" class="icon-remove"></i>
```

And the following functions in my controller's `$scope`:

```
$scope.addName = function() {
    $scope.names.push($scope.newName);
    $scope.newName = '';
};
$scope.delName = function(i) {
    $scope.names.splice(i, 1);
};
```

The `addName()` works fine but the `delName()` is never called. Is it impossible to bind an ng-clik to a function with an argument?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error was in the html, the ng-repeat $index should not be evaluated beforehand:

This is the valid HTML:

```
<i style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="delName($index)" class="icon-remove"></i>
```

Comment: I am having similar problem, updateProductState({{product_id}}), it doesn't trigger the function, but if I hard code a static value it would work. any idea? thanks

Comment: have you tried `updateProductState(product_id)`? You don't need the `{{   }}` in an ng directive

Comment: Thanks. The above helped my problem. Can you explain why `{{ }}` is not needed in a directive?

Comment: @TyMayn In fact it's the other way around, it's because you are not in a directive that you need the `{{ }}`. Most angular directives are evaluating expressions (see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick and http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). The `{{ }}` are used to evaluate expressions outside of a directive in the HTML at compile time (see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolate).

Comment: @plus- Thanks. That helps a lot. God bless stackoverflow :)

Comment: The `{{}}` approach used to work, but changes in a recent angular update

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine to me, can you isolate your problem in a jsFiddle?

EDIT: 
Removed incorrect answer about splice not modifying to array.

Comment: Plain wrong: `splice`does modify the original array and returns the REMOVED items. My problem is the function is never called anyway.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I'm tired I guess. Just answered another question about Array.filter which returns a new array. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows

```
<i ng-click="delName($index)" class="icon-remove"></i>
```

In css

```
[ng-click],
[data-ng-click],
[x-ng-click] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```